# Flow Test Choosing incorrect Lead Process for Lead Status Values

Tags: visual-workflow, leads, status

I'm trying to create some flow tests, but having issues with the lead status field. I have 2 lead processes set up (A and B), each with different lead status values.

When I try to choose a lead status value, the options available to me are from record type A, but I've assigned the lead to record type B. This means I cannot get access to the values that I need.

---

My current workaround is to use the lead import function, but this is tricky when I'm testing a change rather than just a creation. I have to make a lead with the change values, insert that, then make the lead have the initial values and insert that.